# Reading Excel files in a subfolder and how to use subfolder name as a new column value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got a main folder and then I've got folders inside of that for different countries with Excel files.

I was wondering if someone knew how I can read all these Excel files and use the subfolder/country name as a column value.

Then I am planning to concatenate all these files as they are all the same structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

main_folder = './data'

data = []
for xlsxfile in pathlib.Path(main_folder).glob('**/*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(xlsxfile)
    df['dirpath'] = xlsxfile.parent
    data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data)
```